# Take variable outside foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I have a query which show information from two tables in foreach loop on my blade view. This is the controller

```
public function details( $id ){

    $details = Item::find($id)->report;

    return view('details', compact('details'));
}
```

On my view I have

```
@foreach($details as $itemDetails)
    ....
@endforeach
```

Is it possible to show before foreach single variable from this query like?

```
{{ $details->id }}

@foreach($details as $itemDetails)
    ....
@endforeach
```

I want to get the $id.

Comment: To get `id` outside loop because if I want it from the foreach loop I need to put foreach outside one div which then render multiple divs because of the loop...

Comment: can you share structure of sample of $details ?

Comment: Please show result of the `{{ dd($details) }}`

Comment: if you just want the id of first element then you can try something like `collect($details)->first()->id`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Bellow answer is working. I just trying to learn Laravel and some stuffs are kinda not clear yet.

Comment: Is there a difference between `collect($details)->first()->id` and `$details[0]->id`? I mean they are both hard-coded, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, try this:

```
$details[0]->id;
```

Try to understand the concept, every time you use model to get some data it returns an array of object like:

```
array(
    0 => stdClass Object,
    1 => stdClass Object,
    and so on
)
```

So to access the data we use foreach() loop or you can directly call the index as done above.

But if you are calling index directly then put a check for its existence using **isset()**

Comment: its always recommended not to use hard-coded indexing as if can break if index is not available

Comment: @CerlinBoss in your case in the comment above isn't it the same or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes it is highly recommended, and I have mentioned it in my updated answer

Comment: This will show error if `$details` has no records. Try to check the existence of the array with that index then access, try `empty()` or `isset()` functions for that.

Comment: @VLS : On accessing the property `id`, yes but the method `first()` would never throw error instead it will return false if no item found. So a simple if condition would be better